# "Parameter count mismatch" is occurring on the click event of a button in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Error is coming when ever I click on the button

> **Microsoft JScript runtime error:** Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.

```
Function.emptyFunction = Function.emptyMethod = function Function$emptyMethod() {
/// <summary locid="M:J#Function.emptyMethod" />
if (arguments.length !== 0) throw Error.parameterCount();
}//Error is occuring here.
```

Yes, I am using JavaScript confirm message in this page which is included in a master page, update panel and ScriptManager as well on the client click of the button, and after clicking this button error is coming below is my code

```
function Confirm() {
if(document.getElementById('<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').value=="UPDATE")
{
    if(document.getElementById('<%= userStatus.ClientID %>').value=="INACTIVE")
        {
            if (confirm("do you want to make the user INACTIVE? \n By making the user INACTIVE means its all assigned role will be revoked")) 
            {
              document.getElementById("confirm_value").value = "Yes";
            } 
           else
           {
            document.getElementById("confirm_value").value = "No";
           }
        }
   else
   {
    document.getElementById("confirm_value").value = "active";
   }
}
}//endFun
```

Comment: can you provide more information what you are using and paste some code?

Comment: Yes, I am using javascript confirm message in this page which is included in a master page on the client click of the button , and after clicking this button error is coming below is my code..if(document.getElementById('<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').value=="UPDATE")
           {
                if(document.getElementById('<%= userStatus.ClientID %>').value=="INACTIVE")
                    {
                        if (confirm("do you want to make the user INACTIVE? \n By making the user INACTIVE means its all assigned role will be revoked")) 
                        {continued in next post

Comment: here is continued my  code:  document.getElementById("confirm_value").value = "Yes";
                        } 
                       else
                       {
                        document.getElementById("confirm_value").value = "No";
                       }
           
                    }
               else
               {
                document.getElementById("confirm_value").value = "active";
               }
          }
please help..

Comment: can you add this in question? its quite unreadable. You can edit the question and put code.

Comment: I’ve entered my js code above. Actually I am using ScriptManager  in the master page and my page is under Update Panel so I set “ScriptMode="Release" “ and it works now no that error is not coming any more.This is the link which helped me out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344940%28v=vs.110%29.aspx . thanks  Jalpesh Vadgama

Comment: You are welcome. Please close this question so that another person will not try to answer

Comment: @Jalpesh: we don't close questions here unless they are off-topic. In the future, someone may have experience of the same problem, and may have another good answer to add.

Answer (score 15):

I am using `ScriptManager` in the master page and Update Panel so to get rid of this error I set `ScriptMode="Release"` as follows:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ScriptMode="Release" runat="server" />
```

It works now no error is not coming any more. This is the link which helped me out:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmode

Comment: If this is the solution to this problem, don't forget to tick it, to mark it as a helpful answer. We welcome self-answered questions here.

Comment: It works for me.. :) though it still appear on console. But nevertheless, it does not appear on screen :)

Comment: Thanks @Alka Really helpful for me :)